# Typescript only partially inferring generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am currently trying to write a typed react hook, but having trouble doing so. My function looks like this:

```
export const useProjectState = <
  GetStateArgs extends any[],
  StateShape,
  Dispatcher
>(
  state: State<GetStateArgs, StateShape, Dispatcher>,
  ...args: GetStateArgs
): [StateShape, Dispatcher] => {
  const [currentState, setCurrentState] = useState<StateShape>(() =>
    state.getState(...args)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const update = () => setCurrentState(state.getState(...args));
    state.subscribe(update);
    return () => state.unsubscribe(update);
  }, [state]);

  return [currentState, state.dispatchers];
};
```

When I use it though, the shape of the generics is kept but not their types:

[image: Input type]
[image: Output type]

`{ name, author }` is inferred but not `{ name: string, author: string }` for example. I tried to extract the generics from the State type too:

```
const useProjectState = <
  CurrentState extends State<any[], any, any>
>(
  state: CurrentState, 
  ...args: CurrentState extends State<infer GetStateArgs, any, any> ? GetStateArgs : never
): [
  CurrentState extends State<any[], infer StateShape, any> ? StateShape : never, 
  CurrentState extends State<any[], any, infer Dispatchers> ? Dispatchers : never
] => {
```

But this didn't work as well, the types were all turned into `unknown`:

[image: Output with generics extraction through conditional types]

I can't seem to find any way to make it work, might anyone know if I did anything wrong or a way to make that work?

This is what `State` looks like:

```
export interface State<
  GetStateArgs extends any[],
  StateShape,
  Dispatchers
> {
  subscribe: (fn: () => void) => void;
  unsubscribe: (fn: () => void) => void;
  getState: (...args: GetStateArgs) => StateShape;
  forceUpdate: () => void;
  dispatchers: Dispatchers;
}
```

Comment: Could you show the shape of the `State` type?

Comment: @acrazing I updated the post to add the interface definition

Comment: It works in TS 4.3, you may need to check your TS version.

Answer (score 0):

It just works, you can try it here: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=true&ssl=27&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=1#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-FcoPIlBods2CvU6iVzpQZzhZvt9V1Bo1GPdOWdSldAqUnp53r9jrgGfw03aKTSGRyyFj+ALEbgHBg6okuU2xfQ01aZc6ler51r+1oRHs7ccBdcjebKrVKa1qx1LrubJlqEc339FmoABt5vIo-AIRBoTRMNoYJJjJNqZacXF6xIcCBus60hJDPt1DhkDBPNBsi+L2+IhwwjXUADlHymB8n3-GBX0MTYExGCwPyLbQ9G-X8oEKaDnzgi9EM2RoUL4Whon9P5oABIFoxHec4CXaVPlXeFQUPY803YmFTxgc831QSYCyAA).

The link is too long to write a comment, so I created the answer.

Comment: That is confusing me, why would it work there but not locally for me? I am using 4.3.4, same as on the playground.